# Grouped Trailing 7 days vs Yesterday SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an [example schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0f794/1) in `SQL server`. The abbreviated form is as follows:

```
date       group   value
2017-01-01  a      10.00 
.
.
2017-01-08  a      15.00 
2017-01-01  b      10.00 
.
.
2017-01-08  b      15.00 
2017-01-01  c      10.00 
.
.
2017-01-08  c      15.00
```

I would like to have the following, assuming today is `2017-01-08` and `difference` = `yesterday` - `trail_7`

```
yesterday     group   trail_7  yesterday   difference
2017-01-07     a       10.71      15.00       4.29
2017-01-07     b       10.71      15.00       4.29
2017-01-07     c       10.71      15.00       4.29
```

In the above, `trail_7` = `average(values of the last 7 days)` aka six 10s and one 15

## Solution 1

The following worked with the example in fiddle

```
Declare @ReportDate date
set @ReportDate = '2017-01-08'

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, @ReportDate) AS yesterday,
       [group],
       AVG(e.[value]) AS Trail_7,
       y.[value] AS yesterday, --I don't recommend having 2 columsn with the same name
       y.[value] - AVG(e.[value]) AS difference
FROM example e
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT sq.[value]
                  FROM example sq
                  WHERE sq.[group] = e.[group]
                    AND sq.days_date = DATEADD(DAY, -1,@ReportDate)) y
WHERE e.[days_date] >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, @ReportDate)
  AND e.[days_date] < DATEADD(DAY, 0, @ReportDate)
GROUP BY e.[group], y.[value];
```

## Solution 2

```
with atable as (select t.*,yesterday-trail_7 diff
from (select [days_date],[group]
      ,lag(value) over(partition by [group] order by [days_date]) as yesterday
      ,avg(value) over(partition by [group] order by [days_date] rows between 7 preceding and 1 preceding) as trail_7
      from example
     ) t) 
select *
from atable
where days_date = '2017-01-08'
```

Comment: Are you on SQL Server 2017 (per the settings on SQL Fiddle)?

Comment: Is says "MS SQL SERVER 2017"

Comment: How do you get the value `10` for `trail_7`? In testing i'm getting an average value of `10.714285` per group for `'2017-01-01'` to `'2017-01-07'` and `11.428571` for  `'2017-01-02'` to `'2017-01-08'`.

Comment: @Larnu the trailing 7 does not include `2017-01-08`, but it does include yesterday which is `2017-01-07`. So you are right. the average is not 10. It is 10.71 (aka six 10s and one 11)

Comment: @Larnu (aka six 10s and one 15). Sorry for the typos.

Comment: Thanks, @Alex, I have editted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somewhat of a guess, as I have no idea how you get the value `10` for `trail_7` based on the sample data provided:

```
DECLARE @ReportDate date = '20170108';

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, @ReportDate) AS yesterday,
       [group],
       AVG(e.[value]) AS Trail_7,
       y.[value] AS yesterday, --I don't recommend having 2 columsn with the same name
       y.[value] - AVG(e.[value]) AS difference
FROM example e
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT sq.[value]
                  FROM example sq
                  WHERE sq.[group] = e.[group]
                    AND sq.days_date = DATEADD(DAY, -1,@ReportDate)) y
WHERE e.[days_date] >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, @ReportDate)
  AND e.[days_date] < DATEADD(DAY, 0, @ReportDate)
GROUP BY e.[group], y.[value];
```

If you could explain better, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have no missing dates in the table, you can use `AVG` and `LAG` window functions.

```
select t.*,yesterday-trail_7
from (select [Date],[Group]
      ,lag(value) over(partition by [Group] order by [Date]) as yesterday
      ,avg(value) over(partition by [Group] order by [Date] rows between 7 preceding and 1 preceding) as trail_7
      from tbl
     ) t
```

Comment: I appreciate this answer the most

Comment: I tried this in [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0f794/17) and got the error. >`The column prefix 'example' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.` Would you be able to use my same example and reproduce it in sql fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer:

```
declare @t table (dte date,grp varchar(10),val decimal(18,2))
insert into @t
values
    (   '1/1/2017'  ,   'a' ,   10  )
,   (   '1/2/2017'  ,   'a' ,   10  )
,   (   '1/3/2017'  ,   'a' ,   10  )
,   (   '1/4/2017'  ,   'a' ,   10  )
,   (   '1/5/2017'  ,   'a' ,   10  )
,   (   '1/6/2017'  ,   'a' ,   10  )
,   (   '1/7/2017'  ,   'a' ,   10  )
,   (   '1/8/2017'  ,   'a' ,   15  )
,   (   '1/9/2017'  ,   'a' ,   15  )


declare @today date = '1/9/2017'
declare @yest date = dateadd(d,-1,@today)
declare @start date = dateadd(d,-7,@yest)

;with cte as --easier to do math on diff
(
select grp
    ,yesterday=@yest
    ,trail7 = (select avg(val) from @t tsub where dte between @start and @yest and tsub.grp=t.grp)
    ,yestVal = (select val from @t tsub where dte = @yest and tsub.grp=t.grp)
from @t t
where dte=@today
)

select cte.*
    , differnce=yestVal-trail7
from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after:

```
select cast((getutcdate()-1) as date) yesterday
, [group]
, [trail_7]
, [trail_1] --aka yesterday, but we used than name above
, [trail_1] - [trail_7] [difference]
FROM
(
    SELECT [group]
    , avg(case 
        when [days_date] = cast((getutcdate()-1) as date) then [value] 
        else null --null is not counted in the average
    end) [trail_1]
    , avg([value]) [trail_7]
    FROM example
    WHERE [days_date] >= cast(getutcdate()-7 as date)
    group by [group]
) x
order by [group]
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dd89c/1